# How to calculate given time average only

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

Curretly I am using below CDEF settings in my rrdcgi to show day time i.e. 7AM to 11 PM. Is there any setting to calculate the average of perticular time period only. I need to show the 7 day graphs so the average should be of 7 day, day time (7AM to 11 PM) only.

```
<h3>7 Day Performance</h3>
<RRD::GRAPH
        <RRD::GETVAR PATH>/rrdimg/7dayperformance.png
        --title="Performance"
        -w 1048 -h 266
        --imginfo '<IMG SRC=<RRD::GETVAR PATH>/rrdimg/%s WIDTH=%lu HEIGHT=%lu >'
        DEF:p1=<RRD::GETVAR PATH>/data1.rrd:data:AVERAGE
        DEF:p2=<RRD::GETVAR PATH>/data2.rrd:data:AVERAGE
        CDEF:p=p1,p2,2,AVG

        CDEF:gate=p1,POP,LTIME,86400,%,3600,/,FLOOR,DUP,23,LT,*,6,GT,INF,UNKN,IF   #for daytime image
        --end=midnight
        --start=end-7d
        AREA:gate#e0e0ff:"Day time"
        LINE2:p#ff6666:"performance"
```

### EDIT

I am planning to filter out the logs from 7AM to 11PM and create new rrd files to create graphs. Is this a good approch. I dont think so because it will also include the null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `VDEF` to calculate an average, it will build the average of the valid data, since you are already turning the non-office hours data to `UNKN`, all you have todo is to use VDEF and you should get what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Tobi, can you please give me some examples to use this.

Comment: something like this VDEF:avg=p1,AVERAGE

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the same situation where if I could draw a 2nd line in graph where it averages on the same Time frame for the past 7 days

(so like current Monday time of 12:05PM is 480 value minus 1 day of sunday 12:05PM or 86,400 seconds ago for 1 day) or 604800 seconds in a week and then average all 7 into 1 main data (technically maybe average 6 cause we are trying to see what it SHOULD be at this moment) this is like projecting flow based on historical values.

12:05 Sun    value=970

12:05 Sat    value=900

12:05 Fri    value=990

12:05 Thurs  value=940

12:05 Wed    value=900

12:05 Tues   value=940

.

5640/6 and the average at 12:05 is 940 and at the 12:05 in the graph it would draw it

and if its now at monday for Value = 480 but it should be 940 we have a 51% drop or traffic from average (not sure if i need to do that line graph but i can add it in)

Reason why its setup is due to traffic level changes at all times per day due to internet tonnage lol. so say at like 1:05 Tuesday would probally go to